# What Linux kernel subsytem allows reading of a uint16_t from userspace?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, gpio, adc

I'm writing a few kernel modules (as part of porting Linux to a new ARM board).

Most of what I want to expose to userspace fits nicely into the /sys/class/gpio and /sys/class/leds subsystems.

I have a couple of 12 bit ADCs which I want to expose to userspace.

Which subsystem should I use for this?

(Worst-case is exposing them as a character devices which stream the values as newline separated decimal values.  The two ADCs are part of a multi-function-device, accessed over an i2c bus by reading two 16-bit registers.)

I tried returning `42` from a gpio module's `gpio_chip.get` function pointer, but it was changed to `1` by the time it reached userspace.

Comment: Why not expose them as character devices that emit raw binary data? Or you could use a HID-like protocol with the devices.

Comment: Subsystem is called Industrial IO (IIO). @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because there is a specific subsystem for such sensors.

Comment: @0andriy 
 To simplify search: [tag:iio], although not many questions